# jquery - in keyDown erase text from input

Tags: jquery, events, onkeydown

I have a input box that i have some text in site

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Name"/>
```

Now i need to add that when the user starts typing in something (enters the first letter), my text will disappear and he will be able to enter the input he wants.

I tried doing:

```
$('#input').keypress(function () {
                $(this).val("");
            });
```

But then the user can only enter one letter cuz it keeps on deleting the text.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using a placeholder

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/9VhYZ/

Some browser doesn't yet support this, adding a fallback could also be a good idea to support it cross browser:
http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

**UPDATE**:
You can do what you ask for like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/9VhYZ/1/

```
$('#input').one("keydown", function () {
    $(this).val("");
});
```

Comment: Thnaks. Please see what i wrote for karim79

Answer (score 1):

Often this technique is called Ghosting. You can use the placeholder attribute plus progressive enhancement. Often I like to do it by using a class `ghostInput` and having it globally applied on page load so I can add ghost properties to elements simply by appending the global class.

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Name" placeholder="something" class='ghostInput'/>

$(function() {
  $(".ghostInput").focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder")) {
      $(this).val("");
    }
  }).blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
    }
  });
});
```

Often with this you'll want to add and remove another class from the input to make the text appear a little bit lighter which is fairly easy. Just remove it on focus() and add it on an empty blur().

Comment: Nice, but is there a way if doing the above when the user start entering something, cuz i need the input to be focus, in the first place with the text inside.

Comment: Is there anyway to *not* design it that way? It's pretty awkward for users to put have to put in content when content is already there because they don't know where to put their cursor, and theoretically when they type a letter and the field wipes, they lose the character they typed, unless you record and save that character. And it keeps getting more and more complex. But yes you could bind events to `keypress` and `blur`, I just wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I know that wont work, but i want something like the type of thing in this site when asking a new question, in the title of the question, where the text wipes when starting to type...

Comment: @Nucleon The trick is to put the ghost text in a div absolutely positioned behind (if the input is transparent background) or above the input, styled to match. Now, when the field is focused, the cursor will be at the beginning of the input because the input is technically empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the HTML5's [placeholder attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute) instead of JavaScript:

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Name" placeholder="something"/>
```

Be warned - it is not supported everywhere, but if you have the luxury of ignoring older browsers then this is definitely the solution to go with.

Comment: Thanks, never know that before, ill use it for something else. but in this case i need the input box to be focus on when the form opens with the text i put in, and only after the user starts typing it should disappear. (like the type of thing in this site when asking a new question, in the title of the question )

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing the default value of a textbox.

You have two options:

- A plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/default-value
- HTML5's `placeholder="Value"` attribute.

HTML5 isn't supported by all browsers, so I'd try both.